# Convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can someone help me with this series?

Let $C>1$ and $\alpha < 1$, does the series $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} C^{(\alpha^n)}$ diverges?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the stupid question, $ lim_{n \to \infty} C^{(\alpha)^n} = 1$. So the series diverges.